# How do I get the file size of a file located online via PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a PowerShell script that does the following:

- Check whether a specific file exist on the PC
- If it exists, compare the local file size to the online file size. If the online file size is greater than the local file size, download the file. (Checks for an updated version)
- If it does not exist, download the file from the website.

Is it possible to get the file size of an online file without downloading it? I tried using .length but it didn't work. (I'm new to PowerShell)

**PS Script**:

```
$localpath = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\test.csv"

If(Test-Path -Path $localpath)
{
    #Exist, check for an updated version
    $localFileSize = (Get-Item $localpath).length
    $onlineFileSize = (Get-Item 'test.com/test.txt').length

    if($onlineFileSize -gt $localFileSize)
    {
        $url = "test.com/test.txt"
        $downloadFile = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\test.csv"

        (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $downloadFile)
    }
} else
{
    #Does not exist, download the file
    $url = "test.com/test.txt"
    $downloadFile = "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\test.csv"

    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url, $downloadFile)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use `Invoke-WebRequest` and use the `HEAD` method to get just the headers and not download anything. If the resource you're requesting has a known length, then you'll get a `Content-Length` header which you can use, e.g.

```
(Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Head).Headers.'Content-Length'
```