# Powershell script to download files and check integrity of downloaded files

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I've written this powershell script to download files from url. It works fine, but my script only checks file names and if the file downloaded is corrupted, this script doesn't redownload file. Is it possible to do that with powershell? I also need to log error in download_history.log file.

```
$start_time = Get-Date
$download_folder_v3 = "D:\test"
# Download URL list
$page_url_v3 = "http://test.com/example"
$file_path_v3 = "http://test.com/example/v3/"
$files_downloaded = 0
"Starting Download $(Get-Date)" >> $download_folder_v3\download_history.log
# Test for download folder and create if doesn't exist
If (-Not (Test-Path "$download_folder_v3")) {
    echo "creating $download_folder_v3 " >> $download_folder_v3\download_history.log
    New-Item $download_folder_v3 -type directory
 } 
Else {
   echo "$download_folder_v3 already exists" >> 
   $download_folder_v3\download_history.log
 }

$filename_list = Split-Path -Leaf ((Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $page_url_v3).Links.Href)

foreach ($file in $filename_list) {
    If (Test-Path "$download_folder_v3\$file") {
        echo "$download_folder_v3\$file already exists" >> $download_folder_v3\download_history.log
    } 
    Else {
       echo "Downloading $_file_path_v3$file to $download_folder_v3\$file"  >> $download_folder_v3\download_history.log
       Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($_file_path_v3+$file) -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$download_folder_v3\$file"
       $files_downloaded += 1
    }
}
```

**Update**

i've created a list for downloading exe and zip files, is there a way to add only last modified files (uploaded to url) to list:

```
filename_list = Split-Path -Leaf ((Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri $page_url_v3).Links.Href | Where-Object {$_ -match "(^\d*.exe$|\d*.zip$)"})
```

Comment: How to check if the downloaded file is corrupted? You mean if it _gets_ downloaded or not?

Comment: size of downloaded file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but you need to know the checksum of the downloaded files ahead of time, or have a way to retrieve those from the download server. You can verify expected checksums using the `Get-FileHash` cmdlet. As an example, if you know the expected SHA256 checksum of a downloaded file:

```
( Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 C:\Path\To\File.extension ).Hash -eq 'expected_checksum'
```

You can also [check the expected file size using the `Content-Length` header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51430987/584676) (in bytes, and only works if the web server makes this information available) but this is not as accurate as checking the checksum of a file.

```
( Invoke-WebRequest $url -Method Head ).Headers.'Content-Length' -eq ( Get-Item $downloadedFilePath ).length
```

Comment: unfortunately the url only give me file size and date. is it possible to get file size on url and then compare with size of downloaded files?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer on how to read the `Content-Length` header against the download URL.

Comment: thank you. is there a way to use this syntax with foreach and use regex to get size of exe files?

Comment: Yes, you can use my second sample block within the loop to provide the current url and the current downloaded file.